# How can I make dropbox back up folders in my Home Folder like Music?

Tags: dropbox

On Ubuntu I would like to be able to have some of my home folders backed up. Would it also be possible to sync dropbox witht hose folders after a clean install, so that it puts the music folder there? Could it be done in such a ways as to sync across my linux computers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the same issue in my case by linking (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/) my `~/Music` to `~/Dropbox/Music` and storing my music files there.

Here's how I did in my case:

```
mv ~/Music ~/Dropbox/Music
ln -s ~/Dropbox/Music ~/Music
```

If you want to keep all your systems in sync, you have to use the same "trick" on all of them.

Cheers

Comment: Stunts, if you list the steps directly in your answer, instead of linking to them, I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: I read that symlinks were dropped.  Is this no longer a valid solution?