# How can I use Dropbox to back up arbitrary folders?

Tags: dropbox

Symlinks are no longer followed in dropbox, so this answer won't help: [How can I make dropbox back up folders in my Home Folder like Music?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600059/how-can-i-make-dropbox-back-up-folders-in-my-home-folder-like-music)

---

I have photos folder, I'm on Ubuntu, I want to back up my photos.  I don't want to organize my entire system around the drop box folder.  Further, my dropbox folder is on a different HD than my photos are.

What I'd like to do is tell dropbox that the photos folder should also be uploaded, and it's okay to have more than one folder being backed up.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does it have to be backed up the moment you add a new photo, or could you do a cron job to backup? Maybe rclone? https://rclone.org/dropbox/

Comment: If rclone uses disk space, that won't work.  My OS is on a much smaller hard drive than the data I'm trying to back up... but reading this it looks like back-ups go directly to the server.  Can you confirm?

Comment: With rclone you can push your photos to Dropbox, or any other remote service. It is up to you if you allow the dropbox desktop client to sync your photos back to you. You can exclude that using selective sync. Have a look at the link - the first part shows setup and pushing to a remote.

Comment: Ah.  So it'll be one way back ups, but no sync.  Not exactly great for sharing a project between multiple computers... but better than nothing.

Comment: You can do copy or sync in either direction with rclone. You mentioned backup, so I mentioned push.

Answer (score 2):

Annoying, indeed, where Dropbox, for an unknown reason, deliberately decided to break linux symlinks. You can still work around by using `mount --bind` instead. Far less convenient, because you need to be superuser to be able to do this.

The following example of a line in `/etc/fstab` would automatically `mount --bind` a folder `Photos` in `user`'s home folder to a similarly named folder in the Dropbox folder during startup:

```
/home/user/Photos /home/user/Dropbox/Photos none bind,x-gvfs-hide 0 0
```

The `x-gvfs-hide` option prevents the mount from being shown in the left pane of your file manager

Comment: This makes sense.  Basically the same as symlink... but kind of better.  I understood the issue with syncing up a file, then overwriting the symlink with the file on sync-down.  Does this avoid that?  It seems like it may.

Answer (score 0):

Easier method that works for me... I've done this on my Ubuntu install and it works as expected

Move your Documents and Downloads folder to your Dropbox folder and then create a symlink from your home folder to your Dropbox/Documents folder (etc)

Move into your Dropbox folder
cd ~/Dropbox

Make an "Ubuntu" folder (or whatever you might want to call it)
mkdir Ubuntu

Move back to your home folder and move your Documents folder to your Dropbox folder
cd ~
mv Documents ~/Dropbox/Ubuntu/
ln -sf ~/Dropbox/Ubuntu/Documents

That should sync your Documents folder

Follow the same process for any other folders you might want to sync (i.e. Downloads, Pictures, Music, etc)

Hope it helps!!